# Installing Node.js - pros/cons of using Homebrew vs manually managing?

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, nvm

So I'm looking for some info on what the pros and cons are of managing a Node.js package that has been installed manually vs using Homebrew.

Aside from the obvious advantages of having *brew* manage everything for you (as opposed to using *nvm* to keep Node updated), are there any actual problems or potential conflicts to be aware of when managing somethings with *brew* (or via *npm*, *nvm*, etc) and manually?

Comment: Seems like this is an irresolvable issue. Homebrew's reliance on symlnks doesn't seem be a good fit for managing Node (if you have installed Node with default settings). Best fix seems to be to change the default symlink that brew install creates which dumps everything in Cellar directory and point it to the path established when you install node manually. I'll try a couple things and post answer when I'm happy with a workaround.

Answer (score 10):

My situation for application interpreters such as Node.js (or Python or Ruby etc) is that:

- I have many projects, sometimes dozens and dozens
- Each project is either moderately or tightly coupled to a particular interpreter version
- for example, needs Node v0.8.x or v0.10.24
- Installing these interpreters system-wide encourages coupling across projects, so I upgrade node because project8 is ready to upgrade and project3 breaks.

Given these constraints, I install my interpreters per-project because having stability and decoupling is more important to me than other factors such as reducing disk space requirements.

Homebrew is great for project-agnostic tools like `ag`, `git` etc, as well as relatively stable other things like PostgreSQL or MySQL or MongoDB. But for the actual language runtime, the coupling is too tight so I don't use Homebrew for that.

Installing Node.js is just downloading and extracting a tar archive, so honestly you don't need fancy tools. However, I do have a project called [wallah](https://github.com/focusaurus/wallah) that can help with this. You might also look at [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and [envirius](https://github.com/ekalinin/envirius)

Comment: My experience echo's your response - avoid package installers and create self contained projects.

Answer (score 7):

To update `npm` itself you need to run `npm update npm -g`. Where the `-g` stands for global.

Knowing that if you wanted to update global packages installed on your system you would run `npm update -g`

If you don't append the `-g` when you run `npm update` it will attempt to update the local node packages (a.k.a. your current directory `$PWD`). To see if you have any packages installed in the local directory can run `npm list` which will return the following if none are installed:

```
/your/current/directory/
└── (empty)
```

If you do have node packages in that folder you would see something like this (note: this is what returned when I ran `npm list -g`):

```
/usr/local/lib
└─┬ npm@1.4.7
  ├── abbrev@1.0.4
  ├── ansi@0.2.1
  ├── ...
```

You might also want to run `brew update && brew upgrade && brew doctor` to make sure everything is up to date.

My advice for the initial question is to use `brew` because it will save you a lot of headaches in the long run because it can manage almost everything that you install on your computer. Take a look at this https://github.com/nicolashery/mac-dev-setup to see how they set up their dev computers.

Make sure you take a look at this https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask so that you can install apps via `brew cask <app you want>`.

The biggest reason to use `brew` for node is that it installs Node.js and npm at the same time, it uses the `$(brew --prefix)` path but still has its own place in `/usr/local/`. You still use all the same commands as you would if you installed it through the package install. However you can actually uninstall the node and npm by simply running `brew uninstall node` which you can't do with the other ways you install it.

Hope this helps.

---

#### P.S.

If you already have Node.js installed via another method, then `sudo chown $USER /usr/local/*` is your friend. All this does is allow read/write access to all the folders and files in `/usr/local/` which is only needed to fix the links for brew.

Comment: As of writing, you should update globals using "sudo npm update -g"

Answer (score 5):

Some people are reporting `npm update` not working on itself (npm cannot update npm) if installed through Brew.

I would advice manually installing, as NPM will manage node.js updates and packages, while Brew will manage only node.js + npm but not modules. Also Brew is often behind in update releases.

Comment: Ahh, I see. You are referring to this: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/22408

Comment: @pccjamie Yes I am :) Should have added reference to my answer.

Comment: No worries, you pointed me in the right direction. I'll try a few ways and see what works best.

Answer (score 0):

Following are some of the advantages or pros of homebrew over manual installation of node js

1. When installing node via installer you need the `sudo` permission to
   install or un install packages properly.`sudo` lets the installer
   place files in areas of your file system that are only accessible to
   administrators.  One nice thing about Homebrew is that it doesn’t
   require access to administrator-only areas of your computer in order
   to install NodeJS
2. After installing Node via the installer you have to add the path to
   the node executable to your system $PATH.where as in the case of   homebrew, it will take care of the task.

one of the out of the box advantage is it help web developers in installing some missing packages with Mac.